# Is it okay to add CSRF synchronized token by modifying HTML from a valve/filter?

Tags: csrf

Is it okay to modify the html and add a hidden field containing the CSRF token to all the forms inside a page using a valve or a filter before going to the browser?

I'm thinking on this line since I want to remove the responsibility from the developers to add a hidden field to all the forms they develop.

What would be the common/best practice on this?

I understand this implies a degradation on the performance since we'll be parsing the HTML. But is there any other better way?

EDIT: this could also be done using a common javascript that would be included by all the pages:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809056/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-form-before-submit

Comment: Spring Security does something like this. It will inject csrf token if using their `<form:form>` tag